# how to match password with confirm password in registration page in jsp page

Tags: javascript

I have written the following code but on submit it doesn't match password with confirm password..?
what should i do ?
please help..?

```
<script>
          function myFunction(){
              var x = document.getElementsByName("pass").value;
              var y = document.getElementsByName("pass2").value;
              var ok = true;
              if(x !== y)
              {
                  alert("Passwords do not match");
              }
              return ok;
          }  
         </script>
    <h1>Hello ! user, Please register here</h1>
    <form name="f1" action="redirect.jsp" method="POST" onsubmit="return myFunction()">
        First_Name : <input type="text" name="fname" value="" required="" />
        <br>
        <br>
        Last_Name :  <input type="text" name="lname" value=""  required=""/>
        <br>
        <br>
        Email : <input type="email" name="email" value="" required=""/>
        <br>
        <br>
        Date of birth : <input type="date" name="date" value="" required="" />
        <br>
        <br>
        Password : <input type="password" name="pass" value="" />
        <br>
        <br>
        Confirm Password : <input type="password" name="pass2" value="" />
        <br>
        <br>
        Address :
        <br>
        <br>
        Street_No : <input type="text" name="street" value="" size="15"  required=""/>
        Near Landmark(if any) : <input type="text" name="landmark" value="" size="20" />
        <br>
        <br>
        City : <input type="text" name="city" value="" required="" /> 
        State : <select name="state" required="" >
            <option>Select</option>
            <option>Andhra Pradesh</option>
            <option>Chattisgarh</option>
            <option>Dehradun</option>
            <option>Delhi</option>
            <option>Uttar Pradesh</option>
            <option>Punjab</option>
        </select>
        Code : <input type="number" name="code" value=""  required=""/>
        <br>
        <br>
        Mobile number : <input type="text" name="mobile" value="" size="11" required="" />
        <br>
        <br>
        <input type="submit" value="submit" name="s1" />
        <input type="reset" value="reset" />
    </form>
</body>
```

This is my registration page. I would like to match the password and password confirmation fields with javascript, but it's not working.
What should I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The getElementsByName returns an array, so you need to grab the first element:

```
document.getElementsByName("pass")[0].value;
```

Better if you add ids to your inputs and use getElementById.